# Spring Transactional incosistent behaviour

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

In my current project we are using Spring Boot 1.5 with MYSQL 5.7 and jdbcTemplate where
inside a transaction method we are doing first insert and then a get for the same
record. get query is not able to find the record inserted, i am aware that records
are not commited till the transactional flow is commit and hence this case is ok.

The issue is when i am trying to replicate this in a dummy project(i created for
testing) where i did the same thing, here in this case the get query is able to find
the inserted record in a transactional flow. Now this dummy project is having Spring Boot
2.7, MYSQL version 8.2 and JdbcTemplate. Dummy project simple testing implementation
goes like this.

```
@Transactional
//this dummy method is getting called from controller layer
public void dummyMethod() throws Exception {
    doingDBstuff();
    doingDBstuff1();

}

@Transactional
public void doingDBstuff() throws Exception {
    Employee emp=null;
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EMPID,EMPNAME) VALUES (7, 'someName')");

}

@Transactional
public void doingDBstuff1() throws InterruptedException {

    Map<String, Object> dataMap = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap("SELECT empid,empname 
    FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPID=7");
    System.out.println("Employee obect is" +dataMap);

}
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>8.0.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
<artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If the setup is exactly the same it should work. There is one single transaction and you should be able to query it. If it doesn't work in your other system your setup simply isn't the same. ALso you are referring to Spring Boot versions **not** Spring versions in your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum even if the configurations are not same, it should not work in dummy project as well right??

Comment: @Transactional doesn't work for methods in the same class. It looks you have all 3 methods in the same class.

Comment: @Mar-Z the main transactional method dummyMethod is called from controller through bean of this class, it will work.

Comment: If the configs aren't the same you are comparing apples and oranges. But as stated if you are calling that `@Transactional` method externally it should work. So the conclusion, for me, is that your configs, setup and classes are different then what you have in your actual setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum agreed that the configurations might be different but this dummy project is a fresh one which i downloaded from spring.io for teesting this behaviour only, it should have worked right??
I have only added these three db related dependencies 
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

Comment: YOu state in your question that your project is working, now in your comment it is not? Please make up your mind which it is. Also don't include single dependencies but rather `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` or `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc`. That being said if your code is the same as your production one it should exhibit the same issue. So again my conclusion is your code isn't the same and you dumbed down things too much or haven't replicated it exactly.

Comment: @M.Deinum Let me clear things out here, in this dummy project i am getting the data inserted from the select query inside a single transactional flow (as per spring transactional flow it should not happen right??). You can ignore  the actual project where it inserted record is not getting fetched in the single transaction. i have added the dependency in the question itself.

Comment: I give up. Your test project isn't the same as the actual project in regards to code, configuration and what more. You are comparing apples and oranges. There is something in your production code that is **not** in your test code. Be it a final method, a method that is not public, or some configuration you decided to add but omitted here. As stated if it is exactly the same it will work in your production environment as well, testing with dumbed down code wont really help here. Finally please don't add code etc. as comments as that is totally unreadable.